# Trouble with strpos

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use strpos to determine weather a user has submitted a link that includes 'http://', If they do, it is meant to display an error.
Heres my code:

```
$link_url = $_POST['link_url'];
if (strpos($link_url,'http://') !== false) {
header("Location: /addTileError.php?error=E0005");
}
```

If I enter http:// into the string, nothing happens and I am not redirected to the location. Am I using the function wrong?

Comment: if you try to print `$link_url`, what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You are using it correctly.

I suppose the problem is actually that your header command is being sent after other output. The header command only has effect if it gets output before any of your HTML.

Try replacing the header command with a print statement.

Comment: Okay, that worked, Dont suppose you know of any way to use a header function like that though? Idealy I need to redirect the user.

Comment: @Splycd refactor the code so no output before header and please start developing with error checking ON. the error message would of made this solvable in secounds